# k-largest element optimization Swift 3.0

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, sorting

How can an algorithm in Swift 3.0 to find *k* largest element be optimized?

```
 func largestElement(arr: [Int], k: Int) -> Int? {


    let length = arr.count

    if k > 0 && k <= length {

        for k in 0..<length {
          print(k)
        }

        let sorted = arr.sorted() 

        return sorted[length - k]


    } else {
        return nil
    }

}

var arrayOfIntegers = [1, 6, 3, 9, 13, 15]
print(largestElement(arr: arrayOfIntegers, k: 5))
```

What is the best way to eliminate the `sorted()` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) is a well-known
algorithm to find the k-smallest element in an array with an
average complexity of `O(N)`.

Here is a possible implementation of that algorithm in Swift 3.
It uses the same approach as the code example in the Wikipedia article,
but with iteration instead of recursion. Also the pivot element is
not moved to the front of the second partition. That saves some
swap operations but requires an additional check when updating
the lower bound.

```
extension Array where Element: Comparable {

    func kSmallest(_ k: Int) -> Element {
        precondition(1 <= k && k <= count, "k must be in the range 1...count")

        var a = self // A mutable copy.
        var low = startIndex
        var high = endIndex

        while high - low > 1 {

            // Choose random pivot element:
            let pivotElement = a[low + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(high - low)))]

            // Partition elements such that:
            //   a[i] <  pivotElement    for low <= i < pivotIndex,
            //   a[i] >= pivotElement    for pivotIndex <= i < high.
            var pivotIndex = low
            while a[pivotIndex] < pivotElement {
                pivotIndex += 1
            }
            for i in pivotIndex+1 ..< high {
                if a[i] < pivotElement {
                    swap(&a[pivotIndex], &a[i])
                    pivotIndex += 1
                }
            }

            if k <= pivotIndex {
                // k-smallest element is in the first partition:
                high = pivotIndex
            } else if k == pivotIndex + 1 {
                // Pivot element is the k-smallest:
                return pivotElement
            } else {
                // k-smallest element is in the second partition
                // (but not the pivot element)
                low = pivotIndex
                if a[low] == pivotElement {
                    low += 1
                }
            }
        }

        // Only single candidate left:
        return a[low]
    }

    func kLargest(_ k: Int) -> Element {
        return kSmallest(count + 1 - k)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let a = [2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4]
for i in  1...a.count {
    let l = a.kLargest(i)
    print(l)
}
// 4 4 3 3 2 2 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks, @Martin R. Is there any way to make optimize the algorithm without a functional call to the library with as little code as possible?

Comment: @Eric: I have updated the code with "inline" partitioning instead of using a library call. – I am not sure what you mean by "optimizing with as little code as possible". If you don't want to sort then quickselect is a good method. You can also use a max-heap, but I don't think that would require less code.

Comment: Thanks, @Martin R.

Answer (score 1):

This approach of sorting first, then just accessing, is a straight forward technique, but isn't very fast. It's `O(N * log_2(N))`. Small performance optimisations you make to this code can make small improvements but will never improve that asymptotic efficiency. If performance is a concern, you better use the Quick Select algorithm, or some other linear time (`O(N)`) algorithm.

As a side note, here are some improvements I made to your alogirthm to make it more concise, modern swift.

```
func largestElement(arr: [Int], k: Int) -> Int? {
    guard arr.indices ~= k else { return nil }
    return arr.sorted()[arr.count - k]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the optimizations. Is there anyway to avoid `sorted()`?

Comment: That's the bottle neck that makes this O(N * log_2(N)). Using the quick elect algorithm instead is better, as it doesn't sort.